# Bloom Debian Generation

Tags: ros-groovy, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So... I'm trying to package my [p2os-vanderbilt](http://ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt) stack for groovy, and I am having some issues.

Upon running Bloom by the tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease), I received the following error:

```
allenh1@allenh1-Vostro-430:~/p2os-release$ git-bloom-release groovy
Processing release track settings for 'groovy'
Checking upstream devel branch for a package.xml(s) or stack.xml
Cloning into '/tmp/tmp6kdnW0/upstream'...
remote: Counting objects: 569, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (341/341), done.
remote: Total 569 (delta 202), reused 550 (delta 183)
Receiving objects: 100% (569/569), 1.03 MiB | 1.32 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (202/202), done.
stack.xml is present but going to be ignored because this is not a release for Fuerte.
Looking for packages in 'master' branch... found 4 packages.
Detected version '1.0.0' from package(s): ['p2os_urdf', 'p2os_teleop', 'p2os_driver', 'p2os_launch']

Executing release track 'groovy'
==> bloom-export-upstream /tmp/tmp6kdnW0/upstream git --tag 1.0.0 --display-uri https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git --name p2os --output-dir /tmp/tmpi4MO7t
Checking out repository at 'https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git' to reference '1.0.0'.
Exporting to archive: '/tmp/tmpi4MO7t/p2os-1.0.0.tar.gz'
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git archive -o /tmp/tmpi4MO7t/p2os-1.0.0.tar 1.0.0'
 run at: '/tmp/tmp6kdnW0/upstream'
 errcode: 128:
fatal: Not a valid object name
[/vcstools]
Failed to create archive of upstream repository at 'https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git'
'1.0.0' is not a tag in the upstream repository...
'1.0.0' is not a branch in the upstream repository...
Tarball was not created.
<== Error running command 'bloom-export-upstream /tmp/tmp6kdnW0/upstream git --tag 1.0.0 --display-uri https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git --name p2os --output-dir /tmp/tmpi4MO7t'
```

I'm very new to this, so it's probably some kind of obvious git setup thing. Thanks in advance,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65420/bloom-debian-generation/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error that you want to look at in the above snippet is this:

```
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git archive -o /tmp/tmpi4MO7t/p2os-1.0.0.tar 1.0.0'
 run at: '/tmp/tmp6kdnW0/upstream'
 errcode: 128:
fatal: Not a valid object name
[/vcstools]
```

This is git reporting that the `1.0.0` object name does not exist. Later bloom lets you know that `1.0.0` is neither a branch nor a tag:

```
Failed to create archive of upstream repository at 'https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git'
'1.0.0' is not a tag in the upstream repository...
'1.0.0' is not a branch in the upstream repository...
```

Now for best practice you should have a branch called `master`, or `groovy-devel`, and/or `hydro-devel` and so on... This is where you do your work, fix bugs, and add features... When you are ready to release a version *from* that branch, then you create a tag which is exactly that version, e.g. `1.0.0`. With git you can just do `git tag 1.0.0` on the branch you are releasing from.

With catkin packages, you can use the `catkin_prepare_release` script to have it update the version in your `package.xml`, commit that change, tag your repository and push the results. This script helps automate the process and produces a consistent and conventional tagging scheme, and I highly recommend using it. (it is included with `catkin`)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4